# Mysql Multiple Join Perfromance with Django Rest Framework

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-rest-framework, relational-database

I've been struggling with a problem which i believe every one does at some point. I've a small database of 150k products for now. (Increasing as i'm writing this.)

I'm using DRF for the api and been struggling with the categories performance in which i've much products.

I.E I've a category called Dresses which have `34633` products.
How my Database is designed is i've Couple of relations under it.

Product have Categories, Attributes, Color, Sizes, Related Products `M2M`

**Queries**

> Count Query `809.83` ms

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT `catalog_products`.`id` AS Col1 
  FROM `catalog_products` 
  INNER JOIN `catalog_products_category` ON (`catalog_products`.`id` =
                           `catalog_products_category`.`products_id`) 
  WHERE (`catalog_products`.`deleted` = 0 
     AND `catalog_products`.`in_stock` = 1 
     AND `catalog_products_category`.`categories_id` = 183)
) subquery
```

> Result Query `2139.52` ms

```
SELECT DISTINCT `catalog_products`.`id`, `catalog_products`.`sku`,
  `catalog_products`.`title`, `catalog_products`.`old_price`,
  `catalog_products`.`price`, `catalog_products`.`sale`,
  `catalog_products`.`original_categories`,
  `catalog_products`.`original_conv_color`, `catalog_products`.`original_sizes` 
FROM `catalog_products` 
INNER JOIN `catalog_products_category` ON (`catalog_products`.`id` =
                         `catalog_products_category`.`products_id`) 
WHERE (`catalog_products`.`deleted` = 0 
  AND `catalog_products`.`in_stock` = 1 
  AND `catalog_products_category`.`categories_id` = 183) 
ORDER BY `catalog_products`.`title` ASC LIMIT 48
```

as you can see time is so much for a query but here's the tricky part when i apply filters I.E i select color filter and size time start to decrease.

**Queries with filters applied**

> Count Query `264.63` ms

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT `catalog_products`.`id` AS Col1 
  FROM `catalog_products` 
  INNER JOIN `catalog_products_color` ON (`catalog_products`.`id` =
                           `catalog_products_color`.`products_id`) 
  INNER JOIN `catalog_products_category` ON (`catalog_products`.`id` =
                           `catalog_products_category`.`products_id`) 
  INNER JOIN `catalog_sizethrough` ON (`catalog_products`.`id` =
                            `catalog_sizethrough`.`product_id`) 
  WHERE (`catalog_products`.`deleted` = 0 
    AND `catalog_products`.`in_stock` = 1 
    AND `catalog_products_color`.`color_id` = 1 
    AND `catalog_products_category`.`categories_id` = 183 
    AND `catalog_sizethrough`.`size_id` IN (262) 
    AND `catalog_sizethrough`.`stock` = 1)
) subquery
```

> Result Query `351.43` ms

```
SELECT DISTINCT `catalog_products`.`id`, `catalog_products`.`sku`,
  `catalog_products`.`title`, `catalog_products`.`old_price`,
  `catalog_products`.`price`, `catalog_products`.`sale`,
  `catalog_products`.`original_categories`,
  `catalog_products`.`original_conv_color`,
  `catalog_products`.`original_sizes` 
FROM `catalog_products` 
INNER JOIN `catalog_products_color` ON (`catalog_products`.`id` =
                         `catalog_products_color`.`products_id`) 
INNER JOIN `catalog_products_category` ON (`catalog_products`.`id` =
                         `catalog_products_category`.`products_id`) 
INNER JOIN `catalog_sizethrough` ON (`catalog_products`.`id` =
                          `catalog_sizethrough`.`product_id`) 
WHERE (`catalog_products`.`deleted` = 0 
  AND `catalog_products`.`in_stock` = 1 
  AND `catalog_products_color`.`color_id` = 1 
  AND `catalog_products_category`.`categories_id` = 183 
  AND `catalog_sizethrough`.`size_id` IN (262) 
  AND `catalog_sizethrough`.`stock` = 1) 
ORDER BY `catalog_products`.`title` ASC 
LIMIT 48
```

I've tried so many things to fix this but can't get this to be fixed i need to improve the speed of my page load but as the query is taking longer it's not so good for user.
I've used Eager loading so it won't help anymore to improve unless you've any addition to it.

**Code**

> Serializer

```
class ProductsListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

images = ImagesSerializer(many=True, source='get_first_two_images')
related_color = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_related_color(self, obj):
    return obj.related_color.count()

class Meta:

    fields = (
        'id',
        'sku',
        "title",
        "old_price",
        "price",
        "sale",
        "images",
        "original_categories",
        "related_color",
        "original_conv_color",
        "original_sizes",
    )
    model = Products

@staticmethod
def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
    queryset = queryset.only('id', 'sku', 'title', 'old_price', 'price', 'sale', 'original_categories', 'original_conv_color', 'original_sizes').prefetch_related('images', 'related_color')

    return queryset
```

> View

```
class ProductsViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
queryset = Products.objects.all()
permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly]
filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter, CustomFilter, SizeFilter)
filter_fields = ('slug', 'code', 'sku', 'color', 'attributes', 'category', 'original_color')
min_max_fields = ('price', 'sale')
search_fields = ('title', 'original_color', 'original_categories', 'original_conv_color', 'original_sizes')
ordering_fields = ('sale', 'price', 'created_at')
pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

def get_queryset(self):
    if self.action == 'list':
        queryset = self.get_serializer_class().setup_eager_loading(self.queryset.filter(deleted=0,in_stock=1))
        return queryset
    return self.queryset

def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.action == 'list':
        return ProductsListSerializer
    if self.action == 'retrieve':
        return ProductsSerializer
    return ProductsSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a suggestion 
looking to your queries  code 
be sure you have proper composite index  on

```
table catalog_products  index  on (deleted, in_stock, id )
table catalog_products_category index  on  ( categories_id, products_id, id  )
```

and avoid unuseful  ()  around code  ..

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT `catalog_products`.`id` AS Col1 
  FROM `catalog_products` 
  INNER JOIN `catalog_products_category` 
    ON `catalog_products`.`id` = `catalog_products_category`.`products_id` 
  WHERE `catalog_products`.`deleted` = 0 
  AND `catalog_products`.`in_stock` = 1 
  AND `catalog_products_category`.`categories_id` = 183
  ) subquery


SELECT DISTINCT `catalog_products`.`id`
  , `catalog_products`.`sku`
  , `catalog_products`.`title`
  , `catalog_products`.`old_price`
  , `catalog_products`.`price`
  , `catalog_products`.`sale`
  , `catalog_products`.`original_categories`
  , `catalog_products`.`original_conv_color`
  , `catalog_products`.`original_sizes` 
FROM `catalog_products` 
INNER JOIN `catalog_products_category` 
  ON `catalog_products`.`id` = `catalog_products_category`.`products_id`
WHERE `catalog_products`.`deleted` = 0 
AND `catalog_products`.`in_stock` = 1 
AND `catalog_products_category`.`categories_id` = 183 
ORDER BY `catalog_products`.`title` ASC LIMIT 48
```

and last suggestion remember that order  by  has a rather significant effect on the ordering and the fact of introducing a limit to the results implies, however, that all the lines must be selected, ordered and finally extracted only on the basis of the number indicated at the limit.

Comment: Thanks For your reply i already indexed required columns, on catalog_products.id i've "Primary", on catalog_products_category (id, products_id, categories id) i've (Primary, unique, Index). Please let me know if that's okay or i should have index type "index" on all of them.

Also the brackets occurred in my mind but seems they don't do any harm so far queries are faster with brackets i don't know why as i also think it should be other way around.

Comment: show me your table schema  .. the index you mention in your comment   seems not optimal to me

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Again. I figured it out as you mentioned the index i double-check my query and database structure all index were in right place but if you notice i have ordered by title in the query. That was costing all the time here. Thanks for replying Quickly.

Comment: If you can update the answer as i explained I'll accept your answer otherwise I've to write one for others who see this question.

Comment: @ShanKhaliq  .. answer update with some suggestion about order by and limit costing

Comment: Thanks. I'll See that and thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 1):

The optimization of your queries seems quite possible--to be honest. I'm sure it's a matter of using the correct indexes.

I don't know all the details of the column selectivity on each table (that's kind of essential) so I'll assume that, for example, `categories_id = 183` will actually filter out most of the rows; I may be wrong. I will assume a similar selectivity for all related tables (`catalog_products_category`, `catalog_products_color`, and `catalog_sizethrough`).

If that's the case, then I would recommend the following indexes to speed up searches:

```
create index ix1 on catalog_products_category (categories_id, products_id);
create index ix2 on catalog_products_color (color_id, products_id);
create index ix3 on catalog_sizethrough (size_id, stock, products_id);
create index ix4 on catalog_products (deleted, in_stock, id);
```

Try them out. If your queries are still slow, please post the execution plan of the slowest one to interpret it.